# How to show a preloader when LANDING on a NextJS page?

Tags: next.js, preload, next-router

Yes, I know you can do it using the built in router of NextJS, but how do you make it so it shows a loader when you LAND (NOT WHEN CHANGING ROUTES) on the page? For example I perform a reload or I open a new tab and type localhost:3000 to visit the local version of the website. The NextJS Router does not fire events when you land on the page from another website thus the loader does not appear, all you see is the page loading each component. I really hope I am well understood!